# How to compare Javascript array with Papa Parse row.data array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, papaparse

I'm using a fixed array of specific product codes and want to see if any of these are included in each line of a CSV file. I can see both arrays, but when I try to compare for any matching items, it always comes back as false, even when I know there are matches.

So far I've managed to get the CSV file, then parse row by row using Papa parse. I've found JS code to compare arrays that compares the same data correctly in isolation, but I need help making this work when comparing the row.data from Papa Parse.

It's probably something easy, but I'm very new to javascript, so any help would be appreciated.

This is the working comparison code that I'd like to replicate:

```
let b = ["CS165160104", "CS165160105", "CS165160325", "CS166000103", "EN00451003102072M"];
let a = ["CS165160325", "0"];

console.log(a, b, a.some(v => b.includes(v)));

if(a, b, a.some(v => b.includes(v))){
console.log("wazzup")
};
```

This is the JS and Papa Parse code that doesn't seem to produce the same comparison results:

```
$("#parseit").on("click", function() {
  let codestocheck = ["CS165160104", "CS165160105", "CS165160325", "CS166000103", "EN00451003102072M"];
  ///* GET CSV FILE *///
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2725/8056/files/shopify-csv-test.csv?34741';
  Http.open("GET", url);
  Http.send();
  Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    var csvdata = Http.responseText
    ////* PARSE CSV WITH PAPA PARSE *///
    var newdata = Papa.parse(csvdata, {
      header: true,
      step: function(row) {

        let currentcodes = row.data;
        if (currentcodes, codestocheck, currentcodes.some(v => codestocheck.includes(v))) {
          console.log("TRUE")
        }

      },
    })
  }
});
```

I'm assuming that the row.data array isn't in a comparable format to my main array?

Following this, my plan is to gather the matching data into an array and export as a CSV somehow so that users can download it.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`currentcodes.some(v => codestocheck.includes(v))`

You assume that `currentcodes` is always an array because the `some` method belongs to [array's prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Note that you set `header: true` in the config object of `papa.parse` function call.

As said in the [official doc](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#results) :

> `data` is an array of rows. If `header` is false, rows are arrays;
>   otherwise they are objects of data keyed by the field name.

Therefore `currentcodes` won't be an array but an object. The problem is that objects don't have the `some` method by default.

You should use [Object.values(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to transform your object's values to an array. Which could result to `Object.values(currentcodes).some(v => codestocheck.includes(v))`.